# 504 timeout when querying Firebase Realtime Database in Next JS / Vercel

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, next.js, vercel

I'm facing a 504 error (timeout) when making a request to a Firebase Realtime database

[image]

```
import admin from "firebase-admin";

if (!admin.apps.length) {
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert({
      project_id: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
      private_key: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
      client_email: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    }),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE,
  });
}

const db = admin.database();

export default async (req, res) => {
  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      const snapshot = await db
      .ref("properties")
      .child(req.query.slug)
      .once("value");
      
      const properties = snapshot.val();

      return res.status(200).json({ total: properties });
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

};
```

The issue happens here

```
const snapshot = await db
    .ref("properties")
    .child(req.query.slug)
    .once("value");
```

I think the vercel app domain (i.e. the staging domain) needs to be added in GCP as an autorised domain, but I can't seem to find out where.

The request works locally (on `localhost:3000`) so I assume localhost is allowed in GCP.

Any ideas on how to let a Next JS app on Vercel talk to a Firebase Realtime database without a `504` timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using the Firebase REST api to query firebase realtime database